# String operation on DataFrame and Series in Pandas with python

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, concatenation

I just started to learn Pandas.

On my data set, I am running a string operation to remove certain substrings.
input_dataframe is as following:

```
Year   Australian Open   Wimbledon   French Open   US Open
1999   Name1              Name2       Name3         Name4
2000   SUI:Name6(1/4)     Name7       .             USA:Name(1/14)


s1 = input_dataframe["Wimbledon"].str.replace('\(.*|.*\:','')
s2 = input_dataframe["French Open"].str.replace('\(.*|.*\:','')
s3 = input_dataframe["US Open"].str.replace('\(.*|.*\:','')
s4 = input_dataframe["Australian Open"].str.replace('\(.*|.*\:','')
```

Now, I tried to concantenate these 4 series into a DataFrame by running

```
pd.concat([s1,s2,s3,s4],axis=1)
```

but the new DataFrame shows the old DataFrame prior to string operation as well as the modified data.

What is the optimal and effective way to run the string operation on my dataframe? And, is there a way to run string operation on dataframe without creating a series or additional variable?

Comment: You said: "the new DataFrame shows the old DataFrame prior to string operation", can you post a sample of how that new DataFrame looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need assign output to `df`, but first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `Year` and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
input_dataframe = input_dataframe.set_index('Year')
s1 = input_dataframe["Wimbledon"].str.replace('\(.*|.*\:','')
s2 = input_dataframe["French Open"].str.replace('\(.*|.*\:','')
s3 = input_dataframe["US Open"].str.replace('\(.*|.*\:','')
s4 = input_dataframe["Australian Open"].str.replace('\(.*|.*\:','') 

df = pd.concat([s1,s2,s3,s4],axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   Year Wimbledon French Open US Open Australian Open
0  1999     Name2       Name3   Name4           Name1
1  2000     Name7           .    Name           Name6
```

If need some more general solution, need `list comprehension`, because string function like [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) works only with `Series` (columns of `DataFrame`):

```
df1 = input_dataframe.set_index('Year')
df2 = pd.concat([input_dataframe[col].str.replace('\(.*|.*\:','') for col in df1], axis=1)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
print (df2)
   Year Australian Open Wimbledon French Open US Open
0  1999           Name1     Name2       Name3   Name4
1  2000           Name6     Name7           .    Name
```

Or use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
data = input_dataframe.replace({'\(.*|.*\:':''}, regex=True)
print (data)
   Year Australian Open Wimbledon French Open US Open
0  1999           Name1     Name2       Name3   Name4
1  2000           Name6     Name7           .    Name
```